# Python replace method strange behavior

Tags: python, replace

Please help and explain. I tried by adding `max` argument but it didn't help.

```
 key = "tea-1_a-1"
 print(key.replace("a-1","a-2")) # prints 'tea-2_a-2'
```

I need `tea-1_a-2`.

Comment: You have `"te" + "a-1" + "_" + "a-1"` and both `"a-1"` get replaced. As to what how to get what you want, you need to be a bit more specific... For instance if you want last three characters replaced: `key[:-3] + "a-2". Or `"a-1"`, but only as last three characters, you can test those three characters or ending of the string and replace their length on match. Or use `re.sub`. But please, clarify your question a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression would do the job by looking for either the beginning of the string or the underscore character before your pattern:

```
>>> import re
>>> key = 'a-1_tea-1'
>>> re.sub(r'(?:^|(?<=_))a-1', 'a-2', key)
'a-2_tea-1'
>>> key = 'tea-1_a-1'
>>> re.sub(r'(?:^|(?<=_))a-1', 'a-2', key)
'tea-1_a-2'
```

See Python [Regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) documentation for more information.

Comment: I just realised I have two times "a-1" in my string :/

Comment: Oh, I thought the double `a-1` was actually your point and the problem you're trying to solve :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
key = "tea-1_a-1"
print(key.replace("_a-1","_a-2"))
```

Comment: Thanks that works. So there is no a more robust solution? In case when `key = "a-1_tea-1"` your method will not work but I solve that case with `(key.replace("a-1","a-2", 1))`